# How to setup nginx for multiple nodejs apps on a server (using socket.io with namespaces)

Tags: node.js, nginx, socket.io

We have a nodejs app that currently uses socket.io ( with namespaces ). This app is used as a dashboard for a specific financial market. Each instance of app subscribe to a specific market data and provides a dashboard. Initially we were running 3 separate instances of this app configured for 3 separate markets on the server, all binding to separate ports for serving requests.

Since we plan to add more markets it makes sense to have a reverse proxy server where a single port (along with separate URI for each market)  can be used. However, setting up nginx has been a nightmare for various reasons.

(a) each instance of app for a market can be in different development stage and hence can have different static files. Managing all static file via nginx seems painful ? What can be done to leave handling of  the static files with the app itself.

(b) socket.io communication is a failure. We tried to look into network communication and it seems it keeps on getting 404 page not found error when trying to connect to socket.io server. Not sure why it is connecting via http::/localhost/server.io/ instead of ws://localhost/server.io/ ? Can somebody point us to a similar example ? Anything that needs to be taken care of ?

IN our case we have been trying the following inside nginx sites-available/default

```
        location /app/ {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
            #proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

            # kill cache
            add_header Last-Modified $date_gmt;
            add_header Cache-Control 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=0';
            if_modified_since off;
            expires off;
            etag off;

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using nginx as a reversed proxy should not give you a hard time. The great thing about nginx is that you can have multiple projects on the same server with different domains.

Here is an example of nginx with multiple projects:

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name yourdomain.com;

   location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
#Rember to set the header like this otherwise the socket might not work.
    proxy_set_header X-Real-Ip $remote_addr;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
   }
}
server {
listen 80;
server_name subdomain.yourdomain.com;

   location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3001;
   }
}
```

I'm not sure why your socket should fail. Perhaps the mistake is that you try to define the route on the client site. Try having the javascript like this:

```
var socket = io();
```

or if your socket runs on one of your other applications:

```
var socket = io('http://yourdomain.com');
```

And remember that your changes should be added to sites-enabled instead of sites-avaible

Comment: Yep, this seems to work. I was instead trying to have multiple nodes under a single server block (separated by URI like localhost/app1 , localhost/app2 )which was for some reason more painful to setup. Thanks a ton :) !!